# How to fix searching inventory problem in Inventory Program?

Tags: python

I have created an inventory program that has 5 options 1-3 work fine. The problem is option 4. Once you enter an item and a qty in option 1, type 98, then option 4. Now type the item name you entered before. It then prints "Item not in inventory". Instead of printing out the item name and qty in inventory. How do I fix this?

Full Code:

```
import os


name = []

qty = []

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty

def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    menuSelection(CHOICE)

def menuSelection(CHOICE):

    if CHOICE == 1:
        print('Adding Inventory')
        print('================')
        new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        name.append(new_name)
        new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
        qty.append(new_qty)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        indexdel = name.index(removing)
        name.pop(indexdel)
        qty.pop(indexdel)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print('Updating Inventory')
        print('==================')
        item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
        update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
        if update >= 0:
            qty[name.index(item)] += update
            print("Update made")
            CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
            if CHOICE == 98:
                menuDisplay()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        elif update <= -1:
            qty[name.index(item)] -= update
            print("Update Made")
            CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
            if CHOICE == 98:
                menuDisplay()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print('Searching Inventory')
        print('===================')
        search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        if search == name.index(search):
            print ('Item:     ', name.index(search))
            print ('Quantity: ', qty.index)
            print ('----------')
        elif search != name.index(search):
            print("Item not in inventory")
    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 5:
        print('Current Inventory')
        print('=================')
        input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
        printInventory()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()

menuDisplay()
```

Comment: `name.index(value)` returns the _list position_ where the value is found, which will never be equal to a string.

Comment: also, `qty.index` return `<built-in method index of list object at 0x0000000002236C40>`, you should get item by `qty[index]`

Comment: `CHOICE = ...` under `elif CHOICE = 4:` is not indented and after that , `menuDisplay()` under `if CHOICE == 98:` is over indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want your handling of choice `4` to look like (one way):

```
print('Searching Inventory')
print('===================')
search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
pos = name.index(search) if search in name else -1
if (pos >= 0):
    print ('Item:     ', name[pos])
    print ('Quantity: ', qty[pos])
    print ('----------')
else:
    print("Item not in inventory")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I've been pulling out my hair for several hours.